# Is it possible to tell l3docstrip to use another alias than @@?

Tags: symbols, expl3

The `l3docstrip`'s main feature (replacing `@@` by a module prefix) is very nice, except for those whose keyboards don't give a handy access to `@` character (e.g. <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> on French keyboards). Is it possible to tell `l3docstrip` to use another alias than `@@`?

Comment: you don't say what editor you are using but most allow a certain amount of keymapping, if you're not using (say) F9 for anything you should be able to make it insert @ with a single keypress

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using Emacs with already a lot of keybindings, e.g. `F9` is mapped on "Compile" (whatever: `.tex` files, `.py` files, etc.). Hence, what you suggest could be a solution but it would be much easier for me to just type e.g. `**` instead of `@@` :)

Comment: file-save-hook in tex mode do a replace of ** to @@ ? :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you mean "before-save-hook" as mentionned here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-Hooks.html?

Comment: reading the manual is cheating:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you mean RTFMIC? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple question, simple answer: no!

As with the other parts of the DocStrip syntax, for example the fact that `< ... >` is a guard, this behaviour is coded into the program rather than being part of a configuration file or similar. The small number of syntax conventions for DocStrip *define* the format, in the same way that the behaviour of `\foo#1#2` is part of the LaTeX document syntax definition.

Comment: Too bad TeX, LaTeX, LaTeX3, etc. have not been designed by French people ;)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Well `@` is already pretty common in the TeX world. Moreover, I don't see that your access to `@` is really more tricky than mine is for it: I need Shift+ `'` so still two keys, and I have a similar situation with `#` on a Mac keyboard (it's Option+3).

Comment: Two keys is easier to type with two hands: the right one for the (right located) `AltGr` and the left one for the (also right located) `0`, hence the two hands are almost crossed (I guess that's not the case for `Shift`+`'` on QWERTY keyboards). Anyway, I'll try to learn to type `AltGr`+`0` just with my right hand :)

Comment: BTW, if I remember well, a Japanese TeX implementation (format?) used the yen symbol (`¥`) in place of the backslash.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé -- yes, you can see an example of japanese tex input on p.10 of [this 1989 tugboat issue](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-1/tb23gendel.pdf).  (the output is on the previous page.)  but the backslash has a unique `\catcode`, so it's relatively easy to substitute another symbol.  not so with `@`.  (very sorry!)  but if you never want to use `@` for anything else, and you can find another symbol on the keyboard that is never used for anything else, you can type the latter consistently, and then replace it globally with your editor.

Comment: Rather error prone but, thanks to some automatic replacement at saving stage performed by the editor, it is indeed a solution.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Bruno on the LaTeX team is French and so have been others in the past and he actually coded that part. But that aside, two considerations: first of all @ is one of the standards people are used to see and if you are doing any LaTeX coding (2e) you have to use it. Making this flexible would probably possible theoretically, but then you make the source code reading experience worse. In printed format this doesn't matter as it will be replaced but a simple and straightforward standard within the actual file helps a lot and in that respect expl3 is much better@than other c@nventi@ns

Comment: @DenisBitouzé by the way, German keyboard isn't different so much AltGr+Q

Comment: @FrankMittelbach I know Bruno belongs to the LaTeX(3) team: it was a kind of a joke :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé so I gathered ... which is why I didn't end my comment after that statement