# Why spaces are ignored even in textual arguments within \ExplSyntaxOn... \ExplSyntaxOff?

Tags: latex3, text-manipulation

I've seen workarounds for [having the spaces recognized within `\ExplSyntaxOn... \ExplSyntaxOff`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107834/18401). But I wonder why spaces are unrecognized even for (LaTeX3) macros arguments undoubtedly expecting text, e.g. `⟨text⟩` and `⟨more text⟩` in:

```
\msg_new:nnnn { ⟨module⟩ } { ⟨message⟩ } { ⟨text⟩ } { ⟨more text⟩ }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

space is given a catcode of ignore so it doesn't make a token at all, use `~` to make a normal space token

```
\msg_new:nnnn { ⟨module⟩ } { ⟨message⟩ } { ⟨text⟩ } { ⟨more ~ text⟩ }
```

The alternative would be to do something else, but whatever that was it would likely
have the same problems as `\verb` in that it involves catcode changes and so works at the top level but not within arguments of another command, or it would involve some complicated pre-scan to remove or not space tokens that would mean that sometimes you need to hide white space with `%` at end of line, which the L3 syntax is designed to avoid.

Note that in this context `~` is not the active character making a non breakable space construct, it is simply a character with the space catcode that makes a space token as if  from a space in the document setup.

Comment: Perhaps note that at one point we did try having a different catcode situation in exactly this context: it was not a good idea!

Comment: @JosephWright — I don't remember it being not a good idea — since `\msg_new` is only really used in an `\outer`-like context being able to write the message without `~` did save some effort. But it *was* inconsistent with everything else in expl3, so there was a good argument for dropping that feature.

Comment: @WillRobertson That was the 'bad idea' part I was getting at: it wasn't consistent.

Comment: @WillRobertson Too bad, especially because `~` is not easy to type on French keyboards (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/202859/18401 ;)